# Formatting date without lading zero to the day

Tags: vbscript, datetime-format

I writing a code in VBScript, but I cannot get the datetime part right.

I'm using `FormatDateTime(now)`, but the gives not the best result like

```
FormatDateTime(now)
```

`8-01-2016 9:05:12` becomes `01-08-2016 9:05:12`.
`28-01-2016 19:01:18` stays `28-01-2016 19:01:18`.

Has to be:

```
8-01-2016 9:05:12
28-01-2016 19:01:18
```

Is there a way to get both the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `format` argument of `FormatDateTime`.

```
FormatDateTime(now, 2) 'This should return in mm/dd/yy format
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_formatdatetime.asp).

Comment: I alse need the time

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_formatdatetime.asp

> **format** (Optional) A value that specifies the date/time format to use
>   Can take the following values:
>
> 0 = vbGeneralDate - Default. Returns date: mm/dd/yy and time if
>   specified: hh:mm:ss PM/AM.
>
> 1 = vbLongDate - Returns date: weekday,
>   monthname, year
>
> 2 = vbShortDate - Returns date: mm/dd/yy
>
> 3 =
>   vbLongTime - Returns time: hh:mm:ss PM/AM
>
> 4 = vbShortTime - Return
>   time: hh:mm

This should do what you want.

```
od = "28-01-2016 19:01:18"
nd = FormatDateTime(od,0)
MsgBox(nd)
```

Output: `1/28/2016 7:01:18 PM`